# how to fail my bitbucket pipeline when eslint logs errors

Tags: yaml, bitbucket, eslint, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

im writing my first pipeline with bitbucket in yml and was wondering how to fail my pipeline when eslint test results some error and pass only if eslint test has no error logs.
this is how my pipeline looks so far:

```
image: node:14.15.1
definitions:
  caches:
   yarn: ~/.yarn



pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
    - step:
        name: Package Install
        caches:
          - yarn
        script:
        - cd web_app
        - yarn install

    - step:
        name: lint 
        caches:
          - yarn
        script:
         -  cd web_app
         - yarn install
         - yarn run lint
         
    - step:
        name: build
        caches:
          - yarn
        script:
          -  cd web_app
          -  yarn install 
          - unset CI 
          - yarn build
```

will appreciate any help!

Comment: sorry for the stupid question, it happens by default, i mistakenly defined the yarn lint script to always exit with status 0. "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint  --fix src/;exit0" instead of simply "lint": "./node_modules/.bin/eslint  --fix src/",